# keybd_event holds the key down when I want it to press it quickly

Tags: c++

I am building a c++ program that is supposed to use keybd_event to write "o" every time "i" is pressed. However, when I press "i" it presses "o" five times instead of what I want (one time). Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    while (true) {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x49)) {
            keybd_event(0x4F, 0, 0, 0);
            Sleep(1);
            keybd_event(0x4F, 0, 2, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could always just ignore successive key presses, within a certain time window, yourself. Or maybe look into disabling "key repeat" - many libraries/frameworks support that.

Answer (score 0):

`GetAsyncKeyState` will return the state of the key at the time the function is called, from the Microsoft Documentation:

> If the most significant bit is set, the key is down, and if the least
> significant bit is set, the key was pressed after the previous call to
> GetAsyncKeyState. However, you should not rely on this last behavior

and since the Sleep is only sleeping for 1ms the loop will occur multiple times in the time you press the key. You can store the previous state and see if that has changed. But, that isn't guaranteed to work all the time since `GetAsyncKeyState` is asynchronous.

You may want to look into [`SetWindowsHookExA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to solve the issue.